# How to save programmatically made radiobuttons, so they don't disappear when scrolling?

Tags: java, android

I'm having trouble saving the radiobuttons locally on your mobile when they're checked. Every time I scroll through my listview the checked radiobutton disappears, I've checked the internet but 9 times out of 10 the radiobuttons are made in XML files unlike mine.

```
public class Bouw_onderdeel extends Activity {
public String[] naam = {"Bouw onderdeel", "Kapconstructie","Kapconstructieve bevesiging","Doorbuiging","Vochtinwerking","Dakconstructie","Constructieve bevesiging","Doorbuiging","Vochtinwerking","Waterkerende lagen","Waterdichtheid (folie)laag","Lekwaterafvoerend vermogen","Detaillering aan dakvoet","Thermischeisolatie","Bevestiging","Aansluitdetails","Isolerend vermogen","Dakpannen en vorsten","Conditie dakpannen en vorsten","Breukschade","Vorstschade","Afschilfering","Aangroei algen en mos"};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bouwonderdeel_layout);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutBouwonderdeel);  

    ListView list = new ListView(this);
    list.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, naam));

    setContentView(list);

}
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] strings) {
        super(context, -1, -1, strings);
    } 
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //Making the listview.
        LinearLayout listLayout = new LinearLayout(Bouw_onderdeel.this);
        listLayout.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        listLayout.setId(5000);
        //Making the radiogroup
        RadioGroup rbg = new RadioGroup(Bouw_onderdeel.this);
        rbg.setId(3927);
        rbg.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
                );
        rbg.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        //Add the textviews inside the listview
        TextView listText = new TextView(Bouw_onderdeel.this);
        listText.setId(5001);
        //For every listview add 5 radiobuttons
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    RadioButton rbtn = new RadioButton (Bouw_onderdeel.this);
                    rbg.addView(rbtn);
        }

        rbg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);       
        rbg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                //Spot where I wanna save I guess?
            }
        });
        listLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        //Add the radiogroup to the listview.
        listLayout.addView(rbg);
        //Add the listtext to the view.
        listLayout.addView(listText);

        listText.setText(super.getItem(position));

        return listLayout;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your getView method as follows.

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LinearLayout listLayout = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                // Making the listview.
                listLayout = new LinearLayout(Bouw_onderdeel.this);
                listLayout.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                listLayout.setId(5000);
                // Making the radiogroup
                RadioGroup rbg = new RadioGroup(Bouw_onderdeel.this);
                rbg.setId(3927);
                rbg.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                rbg.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                // Add the textviews inside the listview
                TextView listText = new TextView(Bouw_onderdeel.this);
                listText.setId(5001);
                // For every listview add 5 radiobuttons
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    RadioButton rbtn = new RadioButton(Bouw_onderdeel.this);
                    rbg.addView(rbtn);
                }

                rbg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                rbg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                        // Spot where I wanna save I guess?
                    }
                });
                listLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                // Add the radiogroup to the listview.
                listLayout.addView(rbg);
                // Add the listtext to the view.
                listLayout.addView(listText);

                listText.setText(super.getItem(position));

                convertView = listLayout;
                convertView.setTag(listLayout);
            } else {
                listLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.getTag();
            }
            return listLayout;
        }
```

Comment: Really close thanks for the help so far!, but whenever I check the first radiobutton and scroll down it disappears from the top and gets placed beneath the last listitem.

Comment: The same item is repeated twice. so, you're facing such issue

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, care to explain? Thanks in advance

Comment: Assume, if you have 20 rows in the listview and in the first shot you can see 10 rows, In that case, the view in the getView method will have null, later on scroll, the same views are used and those views are not null, so you;re seeing the check of radio button below too.

Comment: Yes, sorry I'm still a beginner with java/android but the view is always null in the first shot, and once you scroll the views receive a different data type instead of null, so the getView method places the null listitems below the not null ones? If that's correct, is it hard to fix such issue?

Comment: Its not hard to fix, Use xml than doing programmatically everything.

Comment: Won't the XML file be mega huge? 

Since I need to add 5*naam.length radiobuttons in each radiogroup?

Comment: No, one row of data will be in the xml, using inflate you will replicate the view multi times in the list view.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for your help I'll try to look into it with inflate. From what I understood is, add 1 listitem in XML and duplicate it with inflate right?